# how to remove xcode ios default launch image

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to remove my app's launch image.
I deleted the two launch image files from my project folder:

Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
and
Default-Portrai@2x~ipad.png

And now get a build errors:
"Can't find .../Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
copypng failed"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is trying to copy these pngs to the bundle. Since you've deleted them from the folder in Finder, Xcode doesn't know that it shouldn't try to copy them.

Choose your project in Project Navigator, then select your application's target, then select the **Build Phases** section and remove those two images from the list of **Copy Bundle Resources**.

Here's a snapshot of a sample project for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Click on your project in the Project Navigator, then go to "General" and scroll down to "Launch Images"

then you can click on each Image you specified to deleted it. 
[image]

If you see the source as "LaunchImage" click on the scroll list and select "Don't use Asset Catalogs".

[image]

[image]

Then you will see the first screen shot where you can change/delete the launch images.

NOTE: That being said, I agree with the previous answer that you need Launch Images to improve the user experience, and give the user the feeling that the app is running and its not only a black screen!

Answer (score 1):

Please read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

You need to provide at least one launch image. If you have removed the current launch image, please provide a new one.

Apple recommends that your launch image should improve user experience:

> "Design a launch image that is identical to the first screen of the
>   app, except for:
>
> Text. The launch image is static, so any text you display in it won’t
>   be localized. UI elements that might change. If you include elements
>   that might look different when the app finishes launching, users can
>   experience an unpleasant flash between the launch image and the first
>   app screen."

Comment: -1 This is not a H.I.G. / ethical question. The OP wants to know how to remove the existing one, probably so that he can add a new one.

Comment: I don't see the reason of a downvote. The OP said he wants to delete the default launch image and so he did by deleting the image files. He then encounters an error. My answer is that he at least needs to have one launch image (because he has none, that is the cause of the error). I am not talking about HIG or ethical reasons, I only tell im that Apple recommends that if he replaces the default launch image, he should do it with a launch images which improves the user experience, including a link to the documentation. So again, why the downvote?

Comment: The OP wants to remove the launch image because he's getting build errors. He is most likely *not* removing the launch image because, aesthetically, he doesn't want one. Your answer isn't really an answer to his question, but rather a warning about not having a launch images in general. I would agree with you though, you need a launch image, but that's not the OP's problem and not a relevant answer. Its a comment more than anything.

Comment: I think you read his question wrong. He specifically asks about "how to remove the default launch image". He explains what he did and "And now get a build errors: "Can't find .../Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png copypng failed". So IMO it is the other way around, the OP initially wants to remove the launch image and is getting build errors but doesn't know how to solve it. My answer is: you need to have _at least_ one launch image, you cannot have none.

Comment: Ok, but... the OP said, "I want to remove my app's launch image" and then mentions his build errors. He did not say "I want to remove my app's launch image ... because I don't want one at all. Why must I have one?" Your answer doesn't resolve his current problem and it assumes he doesn't want a launch image at all. What if he's just trying to delete/replace the existing one?

Comment: The title is "how to remove xcode ios default launch image" followed by the first sentence: "I want to remove my app's launch image". That says enough for me.